# Matplotlib multiple plots with single axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot multiple point-line in the same figure trying to have something generic.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = ['1.33', '1.425', '1.52', '1.615', '1.71', '1.804']
x2 = ['1.38', '1.46', '1.51', '1.6', '1.78', '1.85']

y1 = ['0.02938766388557807', '0.10709677419354839', '0.12921348314606743', '0.18809491888993163', '0.033760186263096625', '0.27248549323017407']
y2 = ['0.024385703648548026', '0.0963855421686747', '0.14084746338645554', '0.23709013673171378', '0.011027278003482298', '0.1826232647199617']

plt.plot(x1, y1, '-o', linewidth=3, markersize=16)
plt.plot(x2, y2, '-s', linewidth=3, markersize=16)

plt.show()
```

But the result is quite bad.

Results:
[image: Results]

I would like to have, for example, on the x_axis tick from 1.3 to 2 with 0.5 step and on the y_axis from 0 to 0.3 with 0.5 step.

Comment: Your values are strings. Convert them to floats before plotting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With list comprehensions used for float conversions:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = ['1.33', '1.425', '1.52', '1.615', '1.71', '1.804']
x2 = ['1.38', '1.46', '1.51', '1.6', '1.78', '1.85']
y1 = ['0.02938766388557807', '0.10709677419354839', '0.12921348314606743', '0.18809491888993163', '0.033760186263096625', '0.27248549323017407']
y2 = ['0.024385703648548026', '0.0963855421686747', '0.14084746338645554', '0.23709013673171378', '0.011027278003482298', '0.1826232647199617']

x1 = [None if i == '' else float(i) for i in x1]
x2 = [None if i == '' else float(i) for i in x2]
y1 = [None if i == '' else float(i) for i in y1]
y2 = [None if i == '' else float(i) for i in y2]

plt.plot(x1, y1, '-o', linewidth=3, markersize=16)
plt.plot(x2, y2, '-s', linewidth=3, markersize=16)

plt.show()
```

Giving:
[image]